# How to make noreply reject mail

Tags: email, postfix, ignore

I am using Postfix to send mail. I have it configured that only users listed in /etc/aliases or /etc/postfix/login_maps are allowed to receive mail and that users must be authenticated and can only send mail from their accounts and not as someone else.

Since I can't send mail out as noreply@example.com, I had to add noreply to the /etc/aliases file. I aliased it to user 'nobody' but when I send mail to noreply@example.com it just loops from noreply to nobody to noc to root and I get an email saying too many loops. Is there another user or another way to have noreply just reject mail completely rather than forward endlessly?

Comment: did you get things working?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the noreply alias and configure [local_recipient_maps](http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html)

> The default setting, shown below, assumes that you use the default Postfix local(8) delivery agent for local delivery, where recipients are either UNIX accounts or local aliases:

to enable the default

```
postconf -e local_recipient_maps=proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```